# jQuery Fullcalendar - optimum number of events on calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

We have events that span single day on fullcalendar.

How many single day events can be show without causing performance problem on typical user browser -- Is it 100 / 150 / 200 - more ?

Related events are grouped together, and are shown/hidden using a list of checkboxes one for each group. Each group typically contains 10-15 events.

How many events would be optimum if we were to hide/show events based on the checkbox clicks - each checkbox click involves looping thru the list of events and identifying which ones need to be shown and this list is rendered at once.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have noticed that getting around 30 events on my calendar can slow things down a little but as far as an upper limit goes I am not sure.  This would depend greatly on what browsers your clients are using. Looking at it form a usability/design standpoint I don't know if I would like a calendar with more than 100 or 200 events on it.

Comment: I have noticed 30-40 events with start-end date spanning multiple days slows down things. From usability point I agree it get messy -- so we are displaying max 4 events per day and rest of the events are accessed using pop-ups. As far as single day events are concerned 4 * 30 days = 120 was what I was thinking.

Comment: Another thing I noticed 120 events in Firefox is super fast compared to IE.